# check ini format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check ini format with python.

is it ok ?

```
>     try:
>             config.read(input_file)
>         except configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError:
>             print(f"Error: {input_file} has no INI format")
```

Comment: did it work when you tried it?

Comment: yes @JuanR. It did work

Comment: I added a more clarifying answer, hope it helps. mark it as accepted if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

The missing section header is not the only error that may arise when parsing an INI file.

You may be better off catching `ParsingError`:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
try:
  config.read('example.ini')
  print("Sections: ", config.sections())
except configparser.ParsingError as e:
  print("Error:", e)
```